# Finding trace of System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, access-violation

When I run project from Visual Studio, after some time of work I see 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll.
But on source tabs there are only "Source not availible". I understand that I have no source of mscorlib.dll but how can I find what part of my project or my libs leads to this issue? Call stack also have only one line.   Is it possible to find at least small part of stack trace? For now from outside it all looks like mscorlib by itself issued some call and crashed on it (lol).
Don't know what to do, I hate such errors because they occurs in 2 - 3 hours time after work, and seems like they come from CefSharp binding (Chromium embedded), which is large project, so I need some way to dig in the code (all compiled with debug information).

PS: When run not from VS, window of application freezes at all (even not falls, but freezes), AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException don't catch this exception (as expected) .NET 4.5, VS2013

Comment: You have to enable unmanaged debugging to see something.  Hmm, CefSharp, look no further.  Odds that you can diagnose such memory corruption are very low.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking placing large chunks of your code in try-catch blocks. Then, when you have determined in which of these blocks the code fails, break this chunk into smaller chunks, and so on until you can narrow down to the exact line in your code that calls the mscorlib.dll that results in the Access Violation Exception.